# SQL-Error : 01S02 [Oracle][ODBC]Option value changed

Tags: sql-server, oracle, odbc

I've application running on sql server but when I'm trying to connect it to Oracle, getting following error while configuration of statement:

```
SQL-State: 01S02  Message: [Oracle][ODBC]Option value changed.
```

on the execution of the statement:

```
SQLSetStmtAttr(hstmt, SQL_ATTR_CURSOR_TYPE, (SQLPOINTER)SQL_CURSOR_DYNAMIC, SQL_IS_INTEGER))
```

**SQL_CURSOR_DYNAMIC** is working fine with SQL SERVER but not with Oracle.
What does it not working for Oracle? 
Please help me! I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could figure it out from Oracle community forum.

`SQL_CURSOR_DYNAMIC` is not supported, we can use `SQL_CURSOR_KEYSET_DRIVEN` instead.

Please refer [this link](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3952911) for more information.